# Two sided bar chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

i need a two sided horizontal bar chart created with d3.js where all sides have positive values:

It should Look like this for example:

http://www.annielytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/sexy-bar-chart.png

I have 3 Categories with each having two values, one shown on the left, the other one the right side of the x-axis.

I found this code, but failed to modify it: [d3.js bar chart with pos & neg bars (win/loss) for each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236682/d3-js-bar-chart-with-pos-neg-bars-win-loss-for-each-record/19818205)

Comment: Did you face any particular problems while trying to edit the code? Was it something not covered in the [many](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) [tutorials](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) [around](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials)? We will be able to help you much better if we know what part you had a problem with.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I tried to modifie the Code, that i have on both Sides of the x-axis Positive Values. i.e. domain from [70,50,25,0,25,50,70]

I modified the D3 Library after Line 8248 to:

   tick[0].forEach(function(a){
          a.childNodes[1].textContent = Math.abs(parseInt(a.childNodes[1].textContent));
        });

Like that i was able to get my wanted result but that cant be the right solution in this case, so im more up for another example which fits better...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at this one and check out the code: 
http://vida.io/discussion/ZETDBs8uePfrmQ24g

It seems to have what you're looking for.