# Grouped bar chart "in one line" with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a particular bar chart with D3.js, and I don't find any example who could match. I would code a bar chart with two series (one negative, and one generally positive) disposed on the same line, but not stacked.

I guess that maybe it's not very clear, so [I've made this on Highcharts](http://raphi.m0le.net/data/BAS/App_d3_strasrk/chute_ries_bastions_ps.html). I want to use D3 to connect the chart with a map I did before.

So, does someone know any example that could help me? Can I sort directly the chart even if my series are unordered? And if the two series are punctually postive, does the little one appear in front of the largest?

Comment: http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBarHorizontal.html ?

Comment: Hi Lars, and thanks for the link. Your example is very close of what I would code but I'm seeking something where series are literally lined up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to order your data, in order to do so, you can use the `[d3.ascending()][1]` functions:

with the following example data:

```
data = [{
    name: "A",
    valueRight: 1,
    valueLeft: 2
}, {
    name: "B",
    valueRight: 4,
    valueLeft: 5
}, ...]
```

We would have:

```
function leftBound(node) {
    return d3.max([node.valueLeft,-node.valueRight])
}

function rightBound(node) {
    return d3.max([node.valueRight,-node.valueLeft])
}
dataSort = function(a,b) {
    res = d3.descending(leftBound(a),leftBound(b))
    if(res==0) {
        return d3.descending(rightBound(a),rightBound(b))
    } else {
        return res
    }
}
```

For reusable charts, you can also use `[selection.sort()][2]` but you have to do this for the 2 bar categories.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgZ6E/55/

ScreenShot:

[image: Screenshot]

The original code is from the following question: [d3.js bar chart with pos & neg bars (win/loss) for each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236682/d3-js-bar-chart-with-pos-neg-bars-win-loss-for-each-record)